How to move a specific value to the end of the array without affecting the order of other elements?
Suppose I have an array of [0,7,4,0,0,8,3,0,0,0,5,6] and I have to take all the zeroes to last positions after other numbers without modifying their order.
So the output array should be like :  [7,4,8,3,5,6,0,0,0,0,0];
How will i get the desired result output using Java 8 , can anyone please suggest
I have tried using the following code
public class ZeroLast {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(0,7,4,0,0,8,3,0,0,0,5,6);
        list.sort(Comparator.reverseOrder());
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}

And the output is : [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
And i know this is because using reverseOrder() mthod it will sort the elements using Descending order and this is not the desired output what it should be . so anything i will do here to get the output or can you please give sample code logic part to get the results and Thanks.

This should help.

As this looks like some homework assignment or similar: are you allowed to use lists? Because your example does nowhere create an array (well, technically speaking the varargs input to Arrays.asList is an array, but you simply use it as varargs parameters)
I'm asking because possible solutions or directions will depend on that. And it's much more convenient to modify a list than an array.

You don't need an additional complexity with sort involved for this operation.

you can use sort method on your list with a custom comparator to do it.
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(0,7,4,0,0,8,3,0,0,0,5,6);
list.sort((o1, o2) -> o1 == 0 ? 1 : (o2 == 0 ? -1 : 0));
System.out.println(list);

Using this all 0s must be at the end of the List without modifying any other order.

You could write the comparator body as Boolean.compare(o1 == 0, o2 == 0).

worth noting that this works because List#sort does a stable sort: it must not reorder equal elements (javadoc)

It seems to me that your comparator does not fulfil the contract of Comparator. Comparing 0 and 0 yields 1. Apparently the sort algorithm in my Java 19 doesn’t detect the failure. Whether the one in Java 23 will, I can’t tell ...

@AndyTurner or just list.sort(Comparator.comparing(i -> i == 0));

You can do this with a loop, shuffling the non-zero elements towards the start of the list:
int dst = 0;
for (Integer e : list) {
  if (e != 0) {
    list.set(dst++, e);
  }
}

Then set the rest of the list to zero:
for (int i = dst; i < list.size(); ++i) {
  list.set(i, 0);
}

Or, more concisely:
Collections.fill(list.subList(dst, list.size()), 0);

This is a linear time operation, with no additional space required beyond the list you are trying to sort.

If you want to do it with arrays instead of collections, the idea from the answer by Andy Turner can still work. You could use a "read" and a "write" index. You read along the array and whenever you hit a 0, you "write" it to the write index. Take care that you search for the first occurrence of 0 as this is the position where you are allowed to start "writing":
int[] array = {0,7,4,0,0,8,3,0,0,0,5,6};
int writePos = 0;
for (int readPos = 0; readPos < array.length; ++readPos) {
  if (0 != array[readPos]) {
    if (readPos != writePos) {
      array[writePos] = array[readPos];
      array[readPos] = 0; 
    }
    ++writePos;
  }
}
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(array));

I put the increment operator outside the assignment statement. Andy’s code is shorter as he used the result of that increment operator which makes it a bit harder to understand.

Isn’t it basically the same idea as the one already posted by Andy Turner? I like the idea, it’s my favourite.

It is the same idea, just implemented with arrays instead of Collections. And Andy shortened it with the use of the result of the increment operator, which makes that solution more suitable for code golf than readability ;-)

List<Integer> nonZeroElements = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> zeroElements = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int num : list) {
            if (num != 0) {
                nonZeroElements.add(num);
            } else {
                zeroElements.add(num);
            }
        }

        // Concatenate non-zero elements with zero elements at the end
        List<Integer> outputArray = new ArrayList<>(nonZeroElements);
        outputArray.addAll(zeroElements);

